# Omitting "Which was"

Tags: ellipsis

In the following sentence, I am not sure whether I can omit "which was". Omitting is suggested to me by a famous grammar software. Wouldn't "developed" then (after omitting) refer to environment? I want develop to refer to "principle". Or is it possible? Which rules apply?

> This paper presents a principle for such environments, **which was** developed during and evaluated through a study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave out *which was* you introduce an ambiguity as the sentence

> This paper presents a principle for such environments, developed during and evaluated through a study.

leaves open the question of whether the principle or the environments were the thing(s) being developed. So it is safer to leave it in.

I would have said *in a study* but that is just personal style.

Comment: Why was this downvoted??